# How to search in java?

Tags: java, search, directory, find

We are asked to make a student and teacher directory that is able to add, edit and searc data. In the search part, my teacher demanded an output that will display all the result that match the input in the search.

sample output:

```
search name: ab

output: 
1. **ab**a, josep jr v.   [IV - Garent]
2. **ab**acada, willie f.   [III - Waling2x]
3. **ab**zal, louie b.   [i - Mercury]


Press the number for details. Zero(0) back to the menu.
Press you choice:
```

***How can I do a search with an output like this??***

I already have

```
public void search(){
    System.out.print("search name : ");

    try {
        searchName = reader.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 


    searchCount = 0;//for search

    for(int i = 0; i<count; i++){

        if(personList.get(i).getName().equals(searchName)){//for search
            searchCount = i;
            break;
        }

    }

    System.out.println(personList.get(searchCount).getName() +" "+ personList.get(searchCount).getAge());

}

String searchName = "";//for search, store search name
int searchCount = 0;//for search
```

Comment: Use `contains` instead of `equals` for the search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do search count = i; you should save the Object you found in a List and then Print out the List, or you print out the items direct.

```
    for(int i = 0; i<personList.size(); i++){
        if(personList.get(i).getName().contains(searchName)){
            System.out.println(personList.get(i).getName() +" "+ personList.get(i).getAge());
        }
    }
```

or

```
    List<person> resultSet = new ArrayList<person>();
    for(int i = 0; i<personList.size(); i++){
        if(personList.get(i).getName().contains(searchName)){
            resultSet.add((personList.get(i))
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<resultSet.size(); i++){
        System.out.println((i+1) + ". " + resultSet.get(i).getName() +" "+ resultSet.get(i).getAge());
    }
```

Comment: what if its like this 
sample output:

    search name: cruz

    output:
    
    1. cruz, rafael f.   [III - Waling2x]
    2. cruztana, marry b.   [i - Mercury]
    3. dela cruz, rofina p.   [IV - Garent]

Comment: what is the problem to creat this sample output? i can gave you an example, but i dont know the methods that you need to get the information you want to print

Comment: the user searched for the word "cruz, then there's a name that has two words (dela cruz). That name should be displayed in the search because the second word matches the word "cruz"

Comment: that will work because contains checks if a String contains another string. "abcd".contains("bc") -> true

Comment: I see. Thank you for being so helpful. Oh! and another thing, once you've search a name, is it possible to edit or update the information under that certain name?

Comment: Yes, but if there are more results you have to check which name the user want to update. Another hint: if you want to make the search not case sensitive, use this if statement: if(personList.get(i).getName().toLowerCase().contains(searchName.toLowerCase()))

Answer (score 0):

Use `String#contains(String)` instead of `String#equals(Object)`.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line of your code to::

```
         if(personList.get(i).getName().contains(searchName)){
            //for search
```

The `java.lang.String.contains()` method returns true if and only if this string contains the specified sequence of char values.

And the `String.equals` compares the string to the specified object. The result is true if and only if the argument is not null and is a String object that represents the same sequence of characters as this object.